# How to generalize outer to n dimensions?

Tags: r, vectorization, reduce, outer-join

The standard R expression `outer(X, Y, f)` evaluates to a matrix whose (i, j)-th entry has the value `f(X[i], Y[j])`.

I would like to implement the function `multi.outer`, an n-dimensional generalization of `outer`: `multi.outer(f, X_1, ..., X_n)`, where f is some n-ary function, would produce a (length(X_1) * ... * length(X_n)) array whose (i_1,...,i_n)-th entry has the value `f(X_1[i_1], ..., X_n[i_n])` for all valid index sets (i_1,...,i_n).  Clearly, for each i in {1, ..., n}, all the elements of `X_i` in `multi.outer(f, X_1,...,X_i,..., X_n)` must be allowable i-th arguments for the function `f`.  For the case n=2, `multi.outer` would do the same thing as `outer`, although it would have a different signature (IOW, `multi.outer(f, X, Y)` would be equivalent to `outer(X, Y, f)`).

It is important to note that, although the arguments X_1, ..., X_n of `multi.outer` are all vectors, they don't necessarily all have the same mode.  E.g. X_1 and X_2 could be `c(1, 2, 3)` and `LETTERS[10:20]`, respectively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is one way: First use `Vectorize` and `outer` to define a function that creates an n-dimensional matrix where each entry is a list of arguments on which the given function will be applied:

```
list_args <- Vectorize( function(a,b) c( as.list(a), as.list(b) ), 
                        SIMPLIFY = FALSE)


make_args_mtx <- function( alist ) {
  Reduce(function(x, y) outer(x, y, list_args), alist)
}
```

Now `multi.outer` just needs to invoke `apply` and `do.call` on this "args-matrix" :

```
multi.outer <- function(f, ... ) {
  args <- make_args_mtx(list(...))
  apply(args, 1:length(dim(args)), function(a) do.call(f, a[[1]] ) )
}
```

Let's try this with an example function:

```
fun <- function(a,b,c) paste(a,b,c)

ans <- multi.outer(fun, LETTERS[1:2], c(3, 4, 5), letters[6:7] )

> ans
, , 1

     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
[1,] "A 3 f" "A 4 f" "A 5 f"
[2,] "B 3 f" "B 4 f" "B 5 f"

, , 2

     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
[1,] "A 3 g" "A 4 g" "A 5 g"
[2,] "B 3 g" "B 4 g" "B 5 g"
```

Comment: Nice!  See a similar (but not as complex) question with a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233308/is-there-a-r-function-that-applies-a-function-to-each-pair-of-columns/5233713#5233713

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
multi.outer<-function(f,...){

  apply(expand.grid(...),1,function(x){do.call(f,as.list(x))})

}
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted the result to be in an n-dimensional matrix, with each dimension corresponding to each argument of `f`.

Comment: +1 for making me aware of `expand.grid`, but when I tried this `multi.outer` (for the first time) with the test function `function (s, b, l) { substr(s, b, b + l - 1) }`, and `c("ABCDEFGH", "IJKLMNOP", "QRSTUVWX"), 1:5, 2:3` as the rest of the arguments, I got `Error in function (s, b, l)  :
  unused argument(s) (Var1 = "ABCDEFGH", Var2 = "1", Var3 = "2")`.  I have not had a chance to figure out what your implementation does, or why this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this using Outer and Vectorize.

```
 sigm = function(a=0,b=0,x){
 return(exp(x*a+b))
 }

 sigm1 = Vectorize(function(a=-1:1,b=-1:1,x){

 outer(a,b,sigm,x)
 },SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Now, sigm1(x=1:3) gives the required output

```
 [[1]]
      [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
 [1,] 0.1353353 0.3678794 1.000000
 [2,] 0.3678794 1.0000000 2.718282
 [3,] 1.0000000 2.7182818 7.389056

[[2]]
       [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.04978707 0.1353353  0.3678794
[2,] 0.36787944 1.0000000  2.7182818
[3,] 2.71828183 7.3890561 20.0855369

[[3]]
       [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.01831564  0.04978707  0.1353353
[2,] 0.36787944  1.00000000  2.7182818
[3,] 7.38905610 20.08553692 54.5981500
```

The only draw back with this code snippet is I am using the default values of a=-1:1 and b=-1:1. When I try to pass the same during function calling, it goes haywire. E.g.

```
sigm1(-1:1,-1:1,1:3)

[[1]]
      [,1]
[1,] 0.1353353

[[2]]
 [,1]
[1,]    1

[[3]]
     [,1]
[1,] 54.59815
```

I am unable to figure out why passing the arguments is making this difference in output.