# Apply function with outer taking the columns of two matrices as the elements of interest

Tags: r

Consider matrices `d` and `r` with `dim(d) = J x D` and `dim(r) = J x R`.
Let fun(a, b) be a function that takes two vectors of the same length and returns some number.
I want to treat the columns of `d` and `r` respectively as my units of interest and apply `outer` to them.

The following code accomplishes this by creating lists of the columns of `d` and `r` and then using both `outer` and `sapply`:

```
d.cols <- split(d, col(d))
r.cols <- split(r, col(r))
outer(d.cols, r.cols,
      function(x,y) {
           sapply(seq_along(x),
                 function(i) {
                     Fun(x[[i]], y[[i]]) })} )
```

The code does what I want and is relatively efficient, but is clumsy and unclear.  Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to get at?

Comment: It would help if you provided sample input/output.  A good sample function would be something simple like `Sum <- function(a, b) a + b`.

Comment: Another related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233308/is-there-a-r-function-that-applies-a-function-to-each-pair-of-columns/5233713#5233713

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are pretty close. As described in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192848/r-how-to-generalize-outer-to-n-dimensions/6193836#6193836), all you need is the `Vectorize()` function to convert your `Fun()` function into a vectorized version:

```
VecFun <- Vectorize( Fun )
```

Then you can simply do:

```
outer(d.cols, r.cols, VecFun )
```

E.g. if you define

```
Fun <- function(a,b) sum(a+b)
```

and `r,d` matrices are defined as follows:

```
J <- 5
D <- 3
R <- 4

d <- matrix( 1:(J*D), J, D)
r <- matrix( 1:(J*R), J, R)
```

then you get this:

```
> outer(d.cols, r.cols, VecFun)

   1   2   3   4
1 30  55  80 105
2 55  80 105 130
3 80 105 130 155
```

Comment: Keep the `Vectorize` examples coming!

Comment: Thanks, also the link was useful.