# Multivariable function operating on an array of vectors in R

Tags: arrays, r, function, variables

I would like to define a multivariable function and then operate on an array of vectors, with the elements of the vectors the values of the variables.  And, replace the array with an array of the outputs of the function.  For a 2-variable version, outer (or outer + Vectorize) works OK.  But for higher dimensions I can't seem to come up with something clean and transparent.

I'll use a two-variable (two-dimensional) example but am interested in a solution that is not restricted to this.

Define vectors of, for example, temperatures and times:

```
temp=seq(10,50,10)
time=seq(5,10,1)
```

This could be used to construct an array using expand.grid

```
arrayInput <- expand.grid(temp=seq(10,50,10), time=seq(5,10,1))
```

The output is an array of 30 rows by 2 columns.  Can now define a function of temperature and time.

```
func <- function(temp, time) time*exp(-1/temp)
```

What I would like to do is rearrange arrayInput so that it is an array with dimension 5 X 6 X 2 and operate on this array with func to generate a 5 X 6 array of values for the function given the pair of inputs, temp and time.

Something like this is straightforward in Mathematica with Apply.  I've found some ways to do this in R, but they are ugly, don't keep the names of the variables etc., which makes it less clear what the code is doing.

Anyone know a nice way of accomplishing this?  As I said, if I have a function of 5 variables, I'd like to be able to carry out the operation in the same way.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: One nice function is `outer`. I think this calculates your desired output, though the input is just the initial vectors: `outer(seq(10,50,10),  seq(5,10,1), function(temp, time) time*exp(-1/temp))`

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned outer in the first paragraph, and it is nice, and maybe I could extend this to higher dimensions outer(outer()).

Comment: Someone took a crack at a 'multi.outer' function here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192848/how-to-generalize-outer-to-n-dimensions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
dim(matInput) <- c(5, 6, 2)
#or matInput <- array(matInput, dim = c(5, 6, 2))

func(matInput[,,1], matInput[,,2])
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
#[1,] 4.524187 5.429025 6.333862 7.238699 8.143537 9.048374
#[2,] 4.756147 5.707377 6.658606 7.609835 8.561065 9.512294
#[3,] 4.836081 5.803297 6.770513 7.737729 8.704945 9.672161
#[4,] 4.876550 5.851859 6.827169 7.802479 8.777789 9.753099
#[5,] 4.900993 5.881192 6.861391 7.841589 8.821788 9.801987
```

However, I don't understand why you need to use an array here. Use a data.frame like everyone else does. R is not Matlab.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to do exactly what you have on the first line, with a data.frame:

    > dfInput <- expand.grid(temp=seq(10,50,10), time=seq(5,10,1))

    > dim(dfInput) <- c(5,6,2)

    Error in dim(dfInput) <- c(5, 6, 2) : 
    dims [product 60] do not match the length of object [2]

I've got no attachment to arrays, or Mathematica (not Matlab), which I haven't used in a decade.  My knowledge of R is poor, because I am only doing this occasionally.  Thanks for the solution.  I need to understand the difference between the two constructs (with and without data.matrix wrapping it).