# Make a 4d array, where each point is corresponds to the result of a function

Tags: r

So I need an array where each point corresponds to a value of a function on those coordinates. Until now, I was dealing with 2d functions so I just did this:

```
  x <- seq(a1,b1, length.out = 10000)
  y <- seq(a2,b2, length.out = 10000)
  func <- outer(x,y,FUN)
```

Where I define the domain of my variables above, and below it generates a matrix where each point is the value of my function "FUN" at those coordinates.
However, now I need to do this for a function that takes in 4 variables.

I want it to be a 4d array but I don't know how to achieve this without resorting to a bunch of 'for' cycles, which I really don't want to.

Comment: Here is a useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192848/how-to-generalize-outer-to-n-dimensions

Comment: `function` is a reserved word in R, so you can't use it as a variable name, at least without forcing it.

Comment: oops, I actually wasn't using it, I was using "function" in my native language and translated it before posting here and totally forgot