# calculate correlation matrix of a matrix with apply

Tags: r, apply

I want to calculate correlation matrix P which each P[i,j]  is correlation coefficient of row i and col j in matrix Data. for example

```
  Data <- matrix(rnorm(500),50,10)
  P <- matrix(0,50,50)
  for (i in 1:50) 
     for(j in 1:50)
        P[i,j] <- cor(Data[i,],Data[j,])
```

But how can I use apply or something like this command to calculate such correlations.

Comment: As stated the request is impossible to satisfy since your rows and columns are not of equal length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `cor()` on a data frame or matrix to obtain a correlation matrix of correlations between all pairs of columns:

```
cor(t(Data))
```

From your question and code it is not clear if you want correlations for all pairs of rows or correlations between rows and columns, but since the matrix is not square I assumed the first.

Comment: Oh, my god, it have a very simple solution Thanks Sacha. but I have a question from you. how can I use two variate function for all pairs of rows of a matrix by apply?

Comment: I had a similar question a while back (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5233308/567015). Easiest way is to use `outer`, e.g. `outer(1:nrow(Data),1:nrow(Data),function(i,j)SOMEFUNCTION(Data[i,j],Data[j,]))`. However this is slow and very often you can find that there is a much easier way to do it.

Comment: Ok, I know that. But I think for having lower system time, there is another way for computing such as apply. I find it and send for you too. 
Re thanks Sacha

Comment: `apply` doesn't really lower computing time. Basically it is just a another way to write a loop. Same as with `outer` really.