# Averaging values between paired columns across a large data frame

Tags: r, apply, mean, sapply, tapply

I have a dataframe consisting of a series of paired columns. Here is a small example.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1000, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(rep(1:12, each=30))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:500, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df4 <- as.data.frame(c(rep(5:12, each=30),rep(1:4, each=30)))
df5 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:200, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df6 <- as.data.frame(c(rep(8:12, each=30),rep(1:7, each=30)))
Example <- cbind(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6)
```

What I would like to do is find an average value for the odd numbers columns (df1,df3,df5) based on the values in the adjacent column, so in the example I would have three sets of averages for each value between 1 and 12. I have managed to apply a function for a specific pair of columns...

```
Example_two <- cbind(df1,df2)
colnames (Example_two) <- c("x","y")
tapply(Example_two$x, Example_two$y, mean)
```

However, the dataframe I will be looking at will be considerably larger so some form of apply function would be ideal to perform this iteratively across each paired set. I have found a similar problem [Is there a R function that applies a function to each pair of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233308/is-there-a-r-function-that-applies-a-function-to-each-pair-of-columns), but I can't seem to apply this to my own dataset.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to get the average value (summary) as a separate dataset or as  columns in Example?

Comment: Seperate dataset preferably, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 mapply(function(x,y) tapply(x,y, FUN=mean) , 
    Example[seq(1, ncol(Example), 2)], Example[seq(2, ncol(Example), 2)])
```

Or instead of `seq(1, ncol(Example), 2)` just use `c(TRUE, FALSE)` and `c(FALSE, TRUE)` for the second case

Comment: @JamesWhite Glad to know that it works.  This could be done in a couple of ways, but I thought `mapply` would be easier